# Cannot resolve this error: Failed to configure a DataSource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am learning Spring Boot and in my first set up I got this problem:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured
```

I looked up solutions on the web and did find some, including those from Stackoverflow, but none of them works.

My simple code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class SpringBootDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String response(){
        return "You made it!";
    }    
}
```

My POM:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hrdb?autoReconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=passw0rd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I also created a file as the following:

```
@Configuration
public class DBConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr?autoReconnect=true");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("passw0rd");
        return dataSource;
    }

}
```

I got the mentioned error either in Unit Test or starting the service. The only way I find out to make it work is to disable data source auto config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Need your help. Thanks.

Comment: Note that you may be missing the dependency containing the driver, see : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Comment: Where exactly are you placing that `application.properties` file?

Comment: @chrylis I put the property file under src/main/resources.

Comment: @Arnaud I have included starter-data-jpa. Is that not enough and I need to specifically include mysql dependency?

Comment: @Z.Wei : Yes, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa doesn't include those drivers, you have to add the driver you need separately.

Comment: @Arnaud Thanks, it works. I misunderstood the tutorial and thought AutoConfig is that magic to config data source for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your DB config - it seems to overwrite Spring's default data source, but the url is different than in application.properties: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hr?autoReconnect=true"

In the properties you have:
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hrdb?autoReconnect=true"

"hr" vs "hrdb".

I would get rid of this class altogether and instead declare the relevant JDBC driver in your pom.xml and let Spring take care of the connection.